# Excel Add in VSTO don't work when other XLA add in are installed

Tags: c#, excel, add-in, xla

I have developed an Excel Add in with C#, and was working fine.
But since i had installed another Add in written in VBS in XLA file, my C# Add in doesn't work anymore...
Does anyone faced this situation before? how can i proceed to resolve that?
Can i create an XLA file fore my add in to force it loads?
Best regards
Sabri,

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling and re-enabling your Addin. This could also be a very specific conflict between actions performed by your addin and the XLA file. Finally, it's possible that your Add-in does actions on the Application.Worksheets() elements and is not properly distinguishing between what the active workbook is (i.e. actions are being performed on the hidden XLA workbook that opens with each instance.)

A world of possibilities, so try some of these resolutions, and if nothing works, clarify your problem with a description of what each add-in does.

Comment: i had tried to do that by changing the loadbehavior entry in the base register but my add-in steel don't load..

Comment: Clarify your problem with a description of what each add-in does.